# PHP Insert value in Array (alphabet key)

Tags: php, arrays

I have array

```
array (
   a =>  "1",
   b =>  "2",
   c =>  "3"
 )
```

If I Insert "4" at position "b". 
old value at position b is move to position "c".
and old value at position c is move to position "d".

**note** position "d" is auto create when Insert value. if key in array is a,b,c,d,e,f,g when Insert value in array, It auto create position "h"

So Result is:

```
array (
   a =>  "1",
   b =>  "4",
   c =>  "2",
   d =>  "3"
 )
```

how do I do? Or have some suggestions

Comment: you need to do $array['d'] = $array['b'] before

Comment: What... How do you do what? Do please elaborate / update your question.

Comment: are u want something like `foreach(range('a','z') as $al){
$new[$al] = $al;
}` ??

Comment: I edit my question. I wish I could explain it more.

Comment: Is there the case that the array just have a,e.And if in this case i insert b,what will happen?

Comment: @Nutto Um....It isn't allow this case. Because I determine the condition that key in array must be sorted alphabetical only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is `addToStack` function using `array_keys`, `array_search` and `array_slice` functions:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' =>  "1",
    'b' =>  "2",
    'c' =>  "3"
);

/**
 * Inserts a new element to stack with offset
 * @param $arr the initial array passed by reference
 * @param $pos string key (position)
 * @param $value inserted value
*/
function addToStack(&$arr, $pos, $value) {
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    $offset = array_search($pos, $keys);
    $rest = array_slice($arr, $offset);

    $arr[$pos] = $value;
    foreach ($rest as $v) {
        $arr[++$pos] = $v;
    }
}

addToStack($arr, 'b', '4');
print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 4
    [c] => 2
    [d] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick may help you.

First of all you need to call the function with `array`, `key` and `value`. In function first check for the key is exist or not. if key exist then store the value, now set the value in array with key and value, find the last key using the `end` function and then increase the value with one for getting the next character, same if key not exist without storing the value.

```
$arr = array (
   'a' =>  "1",
   'b' =>  "2",
   'c' =>  "3"
 );

function array_push_user($arr, $key, $val){
    $store = '';
    $bk = '';
    if(array_key_exists($key, $arr)){
        foreach($arr as $keys => $vals){
            if($keys == $key){
                $store = $val;
                $bk = $vals;
                $lst = $keys;
            }else{
                if($bk != ""){
                    $store = $bk;
                    $bk = $vals;
                }
                else
                    $store = $vals;
                $lst = $keys;
            }
            $arr[$lst] = $store;
        }
        $arr[chr(ord($lst)+1)] = $bk;
    }else{
        end($arr);
        $lst = key($arr);
        $arr[chr(ord($lst)+1)] = $val;
    }   
    return $arr;
}



$ret_arr = array_push_user($arr, 'b', '4');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ret_arr);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 4
    [c] => 2
    [d] => 3
)
```

Comment: should be `c =>  "2",`

Comment: Opps.., let me check.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I did it in my way. But you did it cleverly.